CPLEX: Formulating a combinatorial optimization problem

Let $ a,m,C\in \mathbb{R}^n $ given with
$$ a:=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{pmatrix}\quad m:=\begin{pmatrix}m_1\\\vdots\\m_n\end{pmatrix}\quad C:=\begin{pmatrix}c\\\vdots\\c\end{pmatrix} $$
such that $ a_1\leq a_2 \leq ...\leq a_n $ and $ 0\leq m_k $ for all $ k=1,...,n $.
Further let $ \varepsilon>0 $ be fixed.
Find a permutation $$ \pi:\{1,...,n\}\to \{1,...,n\} $$
such that the unequation
$$ -\varepsilon \leq \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-c)\cdot m_{\pi(k)}\leq\varepsilon \quad (*)$$
is being satisfied with the constraint $$ \min\{m_{\pi(1)}, m_{\pi(2)}\} \geq m_{\pi(n)} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad m_{\pi(1)}\ \geq m_{\pi(n)} \land m_{\pi(2)}\ \geq m_{\pi(n)}. $$

How can I formulate this problem into the way of CPLEX (e.g with Python)? I couldn't find any examples where permutations were used. I already have given the values of the vector components of $ m $ and I need to shuffle them appropiate. I only could find examples with CPLEX were variables were calculated but I don't want to calculate variables. I just want to get a propper permutation.
For more details see my related question link:
Find a propper permutation under given contraint(s)

Please stop flagging questions and say stuff like this question has nothing to do with math! I spent much time to write my question and all what I get is this.

You can model permutation $\pi$ by introducing binary decision variables $x_{ij}$ to indicate whether $\pi(i)=j$ and imposing linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$}
\end{align}
Then $\pi(i) = \sum_{j=1}^n j x_{ij}$ and $m_{\pi(i)} = \sum_{j=1}^n m_j x_{ij}$.
